# turning an abstract queue upside down with stack

Tags: python, stack, queue, abstract

Why does it take 4n calls to turn an abstract queue upside down with the help of an abstract stack? Somebody care to help me with this question please?

Comment: No it isn't, its a question from book that i don't understand the answer to, i can tell my reasoning so far: The abstract stack function removes or adds the top most element in the vector using push or pop, whereas the abstract queue uses "first in first out", so in order to reverse the queue with n elements one would need n calls to get abcd to become dcba, which is wrong?

Comment: I didn't downvote, and am not quite sure why you got downvoted so much (I didn't find it objectionable).  However, a tip for future posts: If you had included your reasoning from the comment in the original post you probably would not have gotten the downvotes.

Comment: Fair enough, I too am surprised, I am new to dealing with queues and stacks and I am sure people find this question ludicrously simple or they probably think it's somebody trying to get solutions for homework without doing the work, but I genuinely can't get my head around it at the moment.

Comment: Again, the more of your own work you show, the better your chances of getting an answer.  Sorry your early SO experience was bad, but stick with it.  This is a great resource.  You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the nodes to end up in the original queue.  In that case you have to remove all the  nodes from the queue one at a time, pushing each onto the stack. So far that's one read (from the queue) and a push (onto the stack).  Then you have to pop nodes off the stack and put them back on the queue.  That's 4 operations per node.